# How is "rax" different from "eax"?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-registers

I'm reading "Hacking: The Art of Exploitation".

In the book the registers are different from the registers that I can see on my pc. These are my cpu registers:

rax,
rbx,
rcx,
rdx,
rsi,
rdi,
rbp,
rsp,
r8,
r9,
r10,
r11,
r12,
r13,
r14,
r15,
rip,
eflags,
cs,
ss,
ds,
es,
fs,
gs

while in the book the registers are:

eax,
ecx,
edx,
ebx,
esp,
ebp,
esi,
edi,
eip,
eflags,
cs,
ss,
ds,
es,
fs,
gs

Can someone explain why they are different? I'm running on an AMD cpu; does AMD have different CPU registers from Intel?

In this case can someone explain me the correspondence between the registers of the two architecture?

Comment: The first set are the 64 bit registers. The second are the 32 bit, which is a subset. You can usually run 32 bit code on a 64 bit processor, just make sure you create a 32 bit program.

Comment: ah finally!! And so in which way can I understand the correspondence? @Jester

Comment: The `e` registers are the low 32 bits of the `r` registers.

Comment: ah ok so the e prefix is for 32bit and r prefix for 64bit? @Jester

Comment: @francescopioGaglione Exactly. Note that you can use the e prefix on amd64, too. This refers to the lower 32 bit of the corresponding 64 bit register.

Comment: Ah Great, thanks a lot!!! I'll try very soon

Comment: Not a perfect duplicate of the linked question, but the answer works perfectly for this.  It even has diagram showing how the low half of RAX is called EAX, etc. etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The registers starting with `r` as in `rax`, `rbx`, etc, are the **64-bit** registers introduced with the [AMD64 extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) to the existing 32-bit x86 ISA. That ISA extension was subsequently adopted by Intel and is often known by the more neutral name [x86-64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86-64). Essentially all x86 chips released in the last decade from AMD and Intel support this ISA.

Registers like `eax`, `ebx`, etc are the 32-bit registers which exist both in the original 32-bit x86 ISA, as well as the 64-bit x86-64. If your book refers *only* to those registers, it is likely that it doesn't cover the 64-bit extension (perhaps it was written before it).

Note that the 32-bit and the 64-bit registers are not separate registers since they overlap: the 64-bit `rax`, for example, has `eax` as its bottom 32-bits, and so on for `rbx` and `ebx`, `r8` and `r8d` and so on. Therefore, modifications to a 32-bit register are reflected in the corresponding 64-bit register, and vice versa.

A similar relationship exists among the 16-bit (`ax`, etc) and 8-bit (`al`, etc) registers. You can find all the gory details in [many places](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture).

Comment: What did you have in mind with that footnote?  `or rax, rbx` where the low half of `rbx` is all-zero?  That writes all of `rax` with a value that happens to be the same as what was there before.

Comment: Just pointing out that the while changing any bit in a 32-bit register always changes the corresponding 64-bit register (indeed even changing 0 bits usually changes the 64-bit reg due to upper-bit zeroing), the "vice-versa" doesn't apply in the case that only the upper bits of a 64-bit reg were changed. @PeterCordes

Comment: But there's no way to modify only the upper bits except with a read-modify-write of the whole 64-bit register like my `or` example.  If you allow that to count, then `or rax, 0x1234` modifies only `eax` half, leaving the upper half of `rax` unchanged...  There's nothing like `mov eax, ebx` that modifies only upper half of RAX the way `mov ah, 1` modifies the upper half of AX.  I'm arguing that you should delete the footnote, because it's more confusing than helpful.  Some may think it implies that there is a way to write (without RMW) to the upper half of a register.

Comment: Yes, by "modify a bit" I mean that the bit changed from 1 to 0 or 0 to 1 with the actual arguments, i.e., it's about the actual change for some execution of the instruction, not what the instruction is capable of across all invocations. So a change to a 32-bit register _always_ produces a change in the corresponding 64-bit register, but the reverse isn't true when only the top bits of a 64-bit registers are modified (even though there aren't dedicated instructions that do that). @PeterCordes

Comment: The existing text is not wrong even for that special case.  A `mov rax, rbx` is reflected in `eax` even if `ebx == eax`.  My main objection is that it might make beginners look for a general-purpose way to write the top half of a 64-bit register, but also that thinking about this special case doesn't add any new insight.  update: just saw your edit.  That's an improvement, and a lot less confusing, but still a distraction.

Comment: Yes, of course, in some sense all operations on a 64-bit registers are _reflected_ in the corresponding 32-bit register, depending on the semantics of _reflected_. One could also argue, however, that as a practical matter an instruction like `btc rax, 50` is never _reflected_ in the lower 32-bits. There is no corresponding case for the reverse direction (modifications of a 32-bit register). Certainly I'm not claiming it adds any insight - it's just an obvious implication of the way the registers overlap. @PeterCordes

Comment: @PeterCordes I just deleted the footnote

Comment: Victory is mine!  :P  The previous update had already made it a lot less confusing, though.

Comment: I concede nothing :) ... but for sure you were right that the note had a negative impact to a typical reader's understanding and that the existing text isn't wrong. The footnote was pendantic without adding anything. @PeterCordes